# .NET Windows Forms - Controls lose visual styles on alternate desktop

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, winforms, pinvoke

I have a .NET Windows Forms application which creates and switches to an alternate desktop using the appropriate P/Invoke methods (`CreateDesktop` and `SwitchDesktop`). It then goes fullscreen by P/Invoke-ing `SetWindowPos` to fill the whole screen.

The problem is that controls on the form do not render with the visual styles; they look like controls from Windows 95 instead of from Windows 7. I have tried using `SetWindowRgn` to make the window's region null ([reason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx)) and tried P/Invoke-ing `InitCommonControls`, but the controls remain unstyled.

How can I make my controls on the fullscreen, alternate-desktop form styled? The application is written in VB.NET, but I can read C#.

Comment: What is the target platform?

Comment: Hmya, there is a Master Switch.  Basic things to check are VisualStyleInformation.IsEnabledByUser and  VisualStyleInformation.IsSupportedByOS

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR .NET 4.5, Windows 7 or higher.

Comment: @HansPassant Both those properties are `True`. I read [something about a Theme service](http://superuser.com/questions/419510/what-does-the-themes-service-do-in-windows-8) which indicates is responsible for doing the nice theming. Is there a way I can get that service going in the alternate desktop?

Comment: This question is heading for the XY Problem Wall at about a thousand miles an hour.  I use Windows 8, pretty sure that code you did not post will work just fine on mine.